# SSL certs showing different expiration date and provider on different laptops

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt

I am bit confused. I am using SSL certs from lets-encrypt for my personal website. On my personal laptop or mobile I see the expiration date as `March 2nd 2024` and provider as LetsEncrypt.

Now, when I used my office laptop which uses zscalar for security/auth the same website is showing expiration as `Feb 2nd 2024` and provider as zscalar. Why is this happening? I can't access one other service that already expired on office laptop because of this issue.

Answer (score 2):

> ... and provider as zscalar. Why is this happening?

The certificate from ZScaler comes from a security solution from the company ZScaler. This means the traffic between a server and your laptop will be intercepted by the ZScaler proxy, decrypted, scanned for potential malicious content and then encrypted again.

This TLS interception is possible since there are actually two TLS connections - one from your laptop to the ZScaler proxy, authenticated with a certificate issued by the ZScaler proxy. And another one between the proxy and the real server, authenticated by the original server certificate.

Comment: Then how do I solve when zcsalar is not updating the cert and one of my service has an expired cert even though real server expiration is in future? Also I don't control anything on zscalar since its the companies security

Comment: @krs: 1. The proxy certificate will be created on demand whenever you access the site (might be cached for some time so that it does not get recreated for every access). So you don't need to worry about the proxy certificate not getting updated - it will happen automatically. 2. ZScaler will validate the certificate of your server - if it is expired or otherwise wrong it will likely propagate the error. 3. Yes, you don't control anything about it but you have to live with your companies decision to use this security solution.